# Как вызвать кнопку созданную в другом классе

Tags: qt, ui

Необходимо соединить через сигналы и слоты кнопку которая находиться в классе **connection**. Вызвать я ее хочу в классе MainWindow и там же слот. Вопрос как прописать указатель на обьект кнопку вначале connect.

Вот кратки пример кода для понимания

```
Class MainWindow .cpp
{
connection = new Connection(this);
connect(connection.ui?,SIGNAL(pressed(bool)), this, SLOT(test_slot()));
}
```

А в классе connection запилена кнопка созданная в дизайнере 
П.С. классы соедены корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас кнопка является атрибутом класса. И логично что приватным. Вам нужно организовать геттер возвращающий указатель на кнопку, и этот геттер в коннект и прописать первым аргументом.
Что то вроде

```
connection = new Connection(this);
connect(connection->p_getButton(),SIGNAL(pressed(bool)), this, SLOT(test_slot()));
```

Но в общем мне кажется у вас нарушенна MVC модель. У вас графическое представление похоже является частью контроллера (connection)

Comment: благодарю за доступный ответ, единственно еще хочу уточнить

сам геттер выглядит что-то вроде:

h: QPushButton *new_button;

new_button Connection::p_getButton()
{

}

Comment: упс недоредактировал...

 
благодарю за доступный ответ, единственно еще хочу уточнить сам геттер выглядит что-то вроде: 
h: QPushButton *new_button; 
cpp:
new_button Connection::p_getButton() { 
new_button = ui->pushbutton;
}

Answer (score 0):

Можно в вашем классе продублировать отправку сигнала от кнопки:

```
class Connection : public QWidget
{
    ...
    Connection(QWidget* parent = 0) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ...
    {
        ...
        connect(ui->pushbutton, SIGNAL(pressed(bool)), this, SIGNAL(buttonPressed(bool)));

signals:
    void buttonPressed(bool);

};

connection = new Connection(this);
connect(connection,SIGNAL(buttonPressed(bool)), this, SLOT(test_slot()));
```

Comment: спасибо за советы в обоих темах, собрав всю информацию в кучу разобрался чего я хочу и самое главное как. Как оказалось задача весьма тривиальная, но у меня не хватало навыков со слотами и сигналами поэтому я их некорректно вызывал.